# How to declare global constants in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

How to declare constants to access in modules, controllers, services and others?
Zend Framework 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean constants literally, just put them in class and you can use them anywhere, for example:

```
namespace Logic\User;

class Type
{
    const ADMIN = 1;
    const EDITOR = 2;
    const READER = 3;
}
```

Use:

```
$userType = \Logic\User\Type::ADMIN;
```

If you understand constants as global, reusable values, try to put them in [ZF3 configuration](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Website_Operation/Application_Configuration.html).